# Shorten .each do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this loop:

```
data.each do |variant|
code = prices[variant["vcode"].to_sym]
  if code.nil?
    reg = sell = sale = " "
  else
    reg = code[:reg]
    sell = code[:sell]
    sale = code[:sale]
  end
  variant["reg"] = reg
  variant["sell"] = sell
  variant["sale"] = sale
```

now, I wanna shorten the code, like what I did with `reg = sell = sale = " "` that before was:

```
reg = " "
sell = " "
sale = " "
```

I wanna do it too with

```
reg = code[:reg]
sell = code[:sell]
sale = code[:sale]
```

and

```
  variant["reg"] = reg
  variant["sell"] = sell
  variant["sale"] = sale
```

and I tried this:

```
  def price_values
    %i[reg sell sale]
  end
```

and replaced

```
reg = code[:reg]
sell = code[:sell]
sale = code[:sale]
```

with

```
reg, sell, sale = code[price_values]
```

but it returns `nil`. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `reg, sell, sale = code.values_at(*price_values)`

Comment: Beware of `reg = sell = sale = " "` is not an exact equivalent of what you had before. Try `reg << "foo"; puts sell` afterward.

Comment: Why do you assign to local variables first and then re-assign their values to the `variant` hash? That looks overly complicated. And why do you have `" "` to indicate a missing value instead of the usual `nil`? What is your code supposed to achieve? Looks like it's doing a bit too much.

Comment: @Stefan the data I gather are all gonna be written in an xlsx document and the requirement is that I provide a blank value if it is nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data.each do |variant|
  code = prices[variant["vcode"].to_sym]
  %w|reg sell sale|.each do |e|
    variant[e] = code.nil? ?  " " : code[e.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Or, even better, with default hash function.

```
data.each do |variant|
  code =
    prices[variant["vcode"].to_sym] ||
    Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = " " }

  %w|reg sell sale|.each do |e|
    variant[e] = code[e.to_sym]
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep. Although something about this whole thing makes me uneasy, but I can't put my finger on it. Is it the weird default value? :shrug:

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the reassignment itself, I’d guess. I’d go with somewhat `data.prices.code` instead of copying a bunch of data from there. Getter might return `" "` on it’s own.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.each do |variant|
  f = prices[variant["vcode"].to_sym] || {}
  [:reg, :sell, :sale].each { |k| variant[k.to_s] = f.fetch(k,' ') }
end
```

See [Hash#fetch](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-fetch).